# Waiting for current location from Core Location when app launches

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm building an app where the first screen is waiting for Core Location to return the current location.

However sometimes ( usually ) the current location hasn't been retrieved via:

```
 locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations [CLLocation])
```

by the time my first views viewDidLoad.

So my question is what is the best way to wait for the current location before my initial views viewDidLoad event occurs?

Comment: You don't. Show some basic UI that indicates that the location is being obtained. You also need to deal with being unable to get the location for any number of reasons.

Comment: Since the user has to allow the app the access the location the first time the app is launched - which will call viewDidLoad before you get access to the location - this will not be possible, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force UI to wait for location update before `-viewDidLoad` will get call. If your application doesn't require hight precision, you can use `location` property from `CLLocationManager` instance. If previously GPS has been used, that value will store information about previous location which has been received by device.